# #039 instead of apostrophe in MySQL database

Tags: php, html

I am doing `$mysqliConnection->query($query);`

where `$query` has `...VALUES ("Hellblade: Senua's Sacrifice", now())...`

And in database it is like `Hellblade: Senua&#039;s Sacrifice`

[image: 1]

Why does this happen?

I even use

```
mysqli_set_charset($mysqliConnection, 'utf8');
$mysqliConnection->query('SET NAMES `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_polish_ci`');
```

And still the same problem. Searched many topics but can't find exactly about this and can't fix it

More code:

```
$gameTitlesImploded = implode(', ', array_column($gamesArray, 'gamesQuery'));
$insertGamesQuery = "INSERT IGNORE INTO games(name, created_at) VALUES {$gameTitlesImploded}";
echo $insertGamesQuery;
die();
$mysqliConnection->query($insertGamesQuery);
```

where `insertGamesQuery` after echoing is...

`INSERT IGNORE INTO games(name, created_at) VALUES ("Hellblade: Senua's Sacrifice", now()), ("................`

Source code:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO games(name, created_at) VALUES ("Hellblade: Senua&#039;s Sacrifice", now()),
```

Comment: Are you using `htmlentities()` or similar functions on the value?

Comment: @Qirel no, it goes straight to the query() functions, exactly as you see it here

Comment: What happens if you execute that query directly on the DB?  (via command line, PHPMyAdmin, some other similar tool).  If it works that way, you should show the code that actually creates and executes the query in your program.

Comment: _“where $query has […]”_ - with `Hellblade: Senua's Sacrifice` actually hard-coded inside the script? Or from a variable? And if the latter, where does that variable originate?

Comment: @PatrickQ Tried to execute the same query but in Navicat (database client software). And it goes normally, like i would want it to be in db `'`

Comment: @pakiecnew Then something in your code (which you haven't shown to us) is doing this.  We can't help without seeing your actual code.

Comment: @pakiecnew You still need to show how `$gamesArray` is populated.  Note that if you are echo-ing out to a browser, the html-encoded string would be displayed as a regular character even if the string has the html entity.  You'd need to view the source to see if it is the html entity or the literal single-quote/apostrophe.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yeah, I added the source now. You are right, in source code there is entity #039 too... But how to bring that to an apostrophe now hmmmm

Comment: @pakiecnew Like I said, you need to show how `$gamesArray` is populated.  The entire process of it.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to make

```
$title = html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

It looked like there is an apostrophe in browser after echoing the variable,  but actually there was entity `#039`.

`html_entity_decode` wasn't enough. I had to apply `ENT_QUOTES`

Comment: ...now on to parameterizing your query